# AWS API Gateway use HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, https, amazon-api-gateway

I have an IoT device that is posting data to an AWS API Gateway. The device can not currently use HTTPS.

Is there any way that I can get the API gateway to accept a standard HTTP POST request?

Comment: Doubtful. Why can't the device use HTTPS?

Comment: It does not include any openSSL libraries

Comment: We are running a Lambda function based on JSON data included in the POST. Is it possible for us to write a PHP script on our own server that sends the data to the Lambda function and then gets and outputs the result

Comment: An IoT  that *cannot* be secure? Why? If there is a way to exploit that weakness, hacker will find it. Use https. Seriously.